# remote: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file

Tags: json, node.js, git, npm

This is the same question:

[npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343997/npm-notice-created-a-lockfile-as-package-lock-json-you-should-commit-this-file)

But the answer did not work when trying to push an update with this code:

```
Js-Mac:Evennode server j$ git add -A
Js-Mac:Evennode server j$ git commit -m "asdd"
[master a1e7bc0] asdd
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Js-Mac:Evennode server j$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 275 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Downloading app
remote: ---> Downloading cache
remote: ---> Restoring cached modules
remote: Loading cached modules
remote: - node_modules (skipping - exists)
remote: - bower_components (skipping - not in cache)
remote: ---> Installing modules
remote: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
remote: npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
remote: 
remote: up to date in 0.32s
remote: ---> Building app image
remote: ---> Uploading app image
remote: ---> Restarting app
remote: 
remote: 
remote: *************************************
remote: *     APP SUCCESSFULLY DEPLOYED     *
remote: *************************************
remote: 
remote: 
To git.evennode.com:c2c3efd78df9974631320f4ce68e7b7d.git
   fd5f549..a1e7bc0  master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

It says commit this file, but the file is nowhere on my Mac. What can I do to remove this error?