# When I try to remove a package, I got this hint: "npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file." How to commit it?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, package, installation

When I try to remove a package, I got this hint:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

added 27 packages, removed 231 packages, updated 5 packages and moved 11 packages in 104.617s
```

I'm not familiar with `node.js`. What's the meaning of these hints? And how can I (and why should I) commit the `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343997/npm-notice-created-a-lockfile-as-package-lock-json-you-should-commit-this-file)

Comment: Thank you very much. But after I read that thread, I still don't know how to commit it (I don't use `git`. I do use `svn` for my code version manage. But I can't understand that is there any relation between my `svn` and the `node.js` files?)

Comment: If it is just a warning/hint, you may try ignoring it, Just incase if you're unable to proceed further, or if it is blocking your executing, try committing using your svn client and check whether you are able to proceed further

Comment: It's just a warning, and it seems not blocking me to proceed further. So I may ignore it, just feeling kind of uncomfortable. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool Benson! :-)